# Provide Error Description When Error Occurs in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I m Trying to get Error Code And Error Description whenever Error is thrown From Try Block and as well as Error Class Name.

Whenever is error is thrown from try block i m getting Exception Class Name But I m not getting Exact Description why Error is occuring i need Description.

```
 catch (Exception e)  {

        System.out.println("########################  
         e.getMessage()"+e.getMessage());

        System.out.println("******************************* 
        e.getLocalizedMessage()"+e.getLocalizedMessage());

        System.out.println("########################## e.getCause() 
         "+e.getCause());

        System.out.println("************************** e.getClass() 
         "+e.getClass().getConstructors());

        System.out.println("************************** e.getClass() 
        "+e.getClass().getName());

    }
```

I want The Error Description why Error is Producing like if 
DataIntegrityViolationException occurs i need on which constraint it just giving DataIntegrityViolationException error.

Comment: You can do that by manually throwing custom exceptions.So ,whenever you need a particular description added you can throw a custom exception with the error description as you like.

Comment: In Order To Do that i should know the Types of Errors Which Might Occur and its Error Code But What i want to do is get the Error Type from Error Message And Display the Error Code and Fetch the Error Message from Error itself nothing from My Side.